# Implementing Angular Universal and my app-root doesn't contain any tags

Tags: angular, angular-universal

After installing angular universal dependencies by using

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject
```

and running it by using `ng serve --port 4000` it didn't encounter any problem.

But when I run it on `localhost:4000` my `app-root` is always empty and  doesn't   contain any meta tags ?

I tried searching for an answer but I didn't find a similar problem.
Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: What kind of meta tags you expect to see?

Comment: Please provide a github repo which reproduces the problem

Comment: i cant  provide github repo  business  project  sorry , and  i want see  meta tag   descript  `<h1>` et `<p>` ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your project ?

This builds your project using the server target, and places the output # in dist/my-project-server/ `$ ng run my-project:server`

To run the app on the server, type the following in a command shell.

```
node dist/server.js
```

To run a production build of your app with Universal on your local system, use the following command.

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```